# Magento CE 1.9.1.0 error 404 with category_widget_link on static page

Tags: magento-1.9, category, widget, link

Using the `category_widget_link` on a static page I get an error 404 when I click on the link in the frontend.
The category page shows up fine. I get this **404** after clicking on the link.
The link that shows up is: `localhost/Magento//Type.1.html__store=default`.
What is wrong and what can be done to prevent this.
I'm testing on a XAMPP 1.8.1 server

Answer (score 0):

try this code..

```
{{widget type="catalog/category_widget_link" template="catalog/category/widget/link/link_block.phtml" id_path="category/462"}}
```